# HTML5-style script-tags in older browsers

Tags: html, cross-browser, script-tag

It has been stated that in HTML 5 it's OK to use `script`-tags for Javascript **without any attributes**, like this:

```
<script>
  // the javascript here
</script>
```

With other features in HTML 5 you can use different kind of poly-fills to bridge what old browsers don't know about HTML 5, but **can above `script`-tag have any side-effect in any old browser**?

***UPDATE**: Let's set the limit at **IE6 and above,** along with **Firefox 2 and above**, to have something concrete.*

Comment: Which browsers do you plan on supporting?

Comment: IE6, IE7, IE8, Firefox 2 maybe. It's all hypothetical so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine everywhere - the default value for type is the one you'd type anyway, as interpreted by browsers. I've used this on every site I've ever made and have never had problems. The same goes for script - no point specifying default values.

The HTML4 spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) says the type is required, though browsers are used to this being malformed (language being specified with no type, `application/javascript` instead of `type/javascript` etc. In short, browsers are used to this being wrong, so they look for script, and don't even parse the attributes as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thank you for contributing with your experience, but I would appreciate some other official sources.

Comment: Your update clarifies things, but I'm basically looking for references that breaks down the argument that "if there is no type set then an old browser might default to VB-script", which is the last piece in the puzzle here.

Comment: That isn't the case, at least in every browser I've ever tried. I guess that super old browsers might not even have javascript, but you probably aren't supporting IE 1 or Mosaic anyway. In short, you will not have any problems in any browser that exists and has been written in at least the last 12 years.

Comment: Yes yes, I know, but give me some official reference and I'll accept! :P

Comment: There isn't any, short of reading the source to these old browsers (which isn't available). This is an empirical observation. You won't find a browser that chokes on this code, so much so that it's been made part of the new standard.