# Do HTML5 Script tag need type="javascript"?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you need text/javascript specified in your <script> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags)

Do in HTML5, the `<script>` tag need attribute `type="text/javascript"`?
I mean isn't it obvious if the `<script>` tag will be contains javascript?

Comment: Note that the other QA used for closing is now obsolete.

Comment: An exactly same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4195427/465053) having equally good answers.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

No, it's [now officially useless](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element).

> The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the
>   data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME
>   type. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default, which
>   is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".

Simply do

```
<script src=yourpath.js></script>
```

(yes, [you can omit the quotes too](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#elements-attributes))

Note that you don't have to worry about pre-HTML5 browsers, all of them always considered JavaScript to be the default script language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401428/html5-style-script-tags-in-older-browsers

Comment: Will `<script src=yourpath.js />` work?

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey No, it wouldn't.

Comment: So I'm reading up on the quote omission link you reference, and, a few lines down, in the `Double-quoted attribute value syntax` section, the example is `<input name="be evil">`.  Does this make the consortium the arch nemesis of Google?

Comment: It is not needed for javascript. It doesn't mean it is useless... I still hope Chrome will include <script type="text/dart"> ..... </script> one day (I can dream, right?)

Comment: @monzonj I already use custom script types myself, or `type="Application/JSON"`, so yes it's not useless at all, but the question was related to JavaScript which should stay the default scripting language for a while.

Comment: @monzonj Dart will not be supported in Chrome anytime soon.  Publicly acknowledged it's pointless without unified support across all the major browser vendors.  They're instead creating build tools that compile to native JS.

Comment: I'm not sure about not using quotes just yet though. Also, a lot of IDEs will shit a brick without the quotes.

Comment: I am so sad about this quote thing. I've validate it and it's valid, also for class and other attributes. Anyway, I will always write it.

Comment: I rarely put those quotes. Just don't use a broken IDE.

Comment: Don't ommit quotes. `<button class="element disable">` != `<button class=element disabled>`. If you ommit you create inconsistencies in the format of your code.

Comment: If you're working on an older project or a project that needs to maintain compatibility with older browsers, you might still need to include the type attribute, according to chatGPT.

Answer (score 12):

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element):

> If the language is not that described by "text/javascript", then the type attribute must be present

And:

> The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".

Conversely, that means that if your `src` attribute is for a file that is valid JavaScript, it is not needed.

Comment: I presume this is not based on the actual .js extension? If the file were script.javascript, I imagine it would still default to javascript?

Comment: @BenHolness - mime types hold these things together. And again, a default is a default - it doesn't matter what the extension is.

Comment: That's what I thought, just wanted to check seeing as you mentioned .js specifically. Thanks!

Comment: @BenHolness - fair point. Answer updated, hopefully removing ambiguity.