# jQuery autocomplete from PHP mySQL query displaying improperly

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, autocomplete

I am using this autocomplete tut: http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/ .

The jQuery aren't displaying. You can actually click the grey line (shown in picture) and it will load everything. I just can't see the names for some reason.

I thought it could be a `css` problem, but I couldn't find anything relevant.

[image: my results look like this]

```
<div class="guestinfo">
        <form action='' method="POST">
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <div class="existingguest"><label>Exisiting Guest</label>
            <input type="text" class="auto" name="guests" id="guests"/></div>
            </div>  
            <div class="existingguestinfo">
            <div><label>First Name</label><input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"/></div>
            <div><label>Last Name</label><input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"/></div>

            <script>
                $(function() {
                    $('.auto').val("");

                    $(".auto").autocomplete({
                        source: "classes/autocomplete_guests.php",
                        minLength: 1,
                        select: function(event, ui) {
                            $('#firstname').val(ui.item.fname);
                            $('#lastname').val(ui.item.lname);
                            $('#address').val(ui.item.address);
                            $('#phone').val(ui.item.phone);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <!--<div><label>Add New Guest</label></div>-->
            <div><label>Address</label><input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="address" name="address"/></div>

            <div><label>Phone</label><input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="phone" name="phone"/></div>
            </br></div>
        </form>
    </div>  <!-- end guestinfo div -->
```

autocomplete_guests.php

```
<?php
//open connection
require_once('../config/db.php');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

$return_arr = array();

/* If connection to database, run sql statement. */
if ($con)
{
    $fetch = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM guests WHERE lname like '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['term'])."%'");

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $row_array['lname'] = $row['lname'];
        $row_array['fname'] = $row['fname'];
        $row_array['gender'] = $row['gender'];
        $row_array['address'] = $row['address'];
        $row_array['city'] = $row['city'];
        $row_array['state'] = $row['state'];
        $row_array['phone'] = $row['phone'];
        $row_array['email'] = $row['email'];
        $row_array['dob'] = $row['dob'];
        $row_array['zip'] = $row['zip'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
}

/* Free connection resources. */
mysqli_close($con);

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Comment: "it will load everything" Do you mean the suggestions list you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, everything I expect to be in the list is in fact in the list. I just cannot visually see them other than the grey bar.

Comment: Can you see with chrome dev tools that the values have actually been loaded into the DOM? or is there an onclick action that might be happening afterwards?

Comment: I can actually click the grey bar and it loads the data into the textboxes for me. So obviously everything on the data end is working properly. I am just having display issues.

Comment: In the link, there is a `<p>` with the ui class wrapping the inputs. You have a div with the ui class wrapping the inputs which are inside divs themselves. So unless you provide a link to your form or a jsfiddle is going to be almost impossible to work out the issue from the screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should

1) write script tags like `<script type="text/javascript">`

2) Put your javascript at the bottom of the page and not half way through the form... (?!!)

3) Add a document ready to that function so that it executes when the page finished loading. 
`$( document ).ready(function() {`

4) Make sure you have included all the required jquery files: Jquery Core, Jquery UI, etc.

5) Provide some CSS if you think that is the problem??

EDIT:

Ignore 3. Ive just looked at the plugin documentation.

Comment: Check, check, and check. I still have the same issue.

Comment: I am using this css: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css I honestly wouldn't know where to start and why it would be messed up in the first pace.

Comment: That css works - http://jsfiddle.net/Yq24R/ (ive copied the JS variable from JqueryUI as cant run php in there). I would suggest removing any other css file you might be linking to

Comment: i removed all of my css other than that and it still happens.

Comment: Ok, think i know the issue. You have the data for the other inputs but not the data for the autocomplete. The demo has the keys in the array of 'id', 'value' and 'abbrev'. The first one and the last one are assigned on selection of an option. The options are built from the value key.

Add a value key to your array. ie:
`$row_array['value'] = $row['lname']. .$row['fname'];`

Comment: Further reading the documentation...
A ‘value’ and/or a ‘label’ field is mandatory for the autocomplete to work. See explanation at bottom of post.

So, as first thought, all the required data is not in the DOM. This is not a css issue.

Comment: SOB it worked! I remember being fuzzy when I typed all that out but never thought to go back and mess with it. It now only displays the first name `fname` How can I get it to display both?

Comment: Don't include the [type attribute in the script tag either](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14323399/1946636).

Comment: Sorry! got over excited!!! use: `$row_array['value'] = $row['lname']." ".$row['fname'];` to concatenate the names

Comment: I got it `$row_array['value'] = $row['lname'].', '.$row['fname'];` Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Just try these lines inside  before ur Jquery script

====sorry if am wrong =====