# Is it bad practice to not include type="text/css" in style tags?

Tags: html, css

It would appear that all modern browsers assume the type attribute for a style tag to be "text/css" by default. Is it considered bad practice to omit the type attribute when using the style tag? And are there any instances where not using the type attribute could lead to unexpected results?

Comment: I have yet to see a browser choke with that missing. Validators might get pissy about it, but most browsers take it in stride. That said, there's really no drawback by leaving it in.

Comment: @Matt the question is similar to the <link> tag question; however, I was explicitly asking about <style> tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the W3.org wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/style) :

> The default value for the type attribute, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/css"

So no, you don't need it, as it was always the default value and it's now explicitly optional.

Comment: same goes for text/javascript

Comment: @Mark [Yes, I could use almost the same wording here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323376/do-html5-script-tag-need-type-javascript/14323399#14323399) ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using HTML5 you can safely ignore it as it's no longer needed.  HTML4 pages will throw an error on validation.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 version is the version that allows you to *not have* this attribute. But in previous versions you were required to write this in the `<link>` attribute.

Here is a link to the W3 Org, http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/present/styles.html

> Otherwise, the default style sheet language is "text/css".

This is the 3rd item from the list of the naming content type Setting pane. Read the doc for more.

Answer (score 0):

in html5 you don't need to use this attribute, so you can allow using this...but in other version you have to add this :-D ... html5 give you facilities :-D