# over simple issue : checkbox calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, django

I can't see why this doesn't work

I got an "handle_email" is not defined error :-(

I am on using django. It is difficult to see why it doesn't work :( so simple !! I can't really put all the code because stackoverflow doesn't allow me to have only code on this question ;)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<script type="text/script">
  function calculate_colspan(x){ return Math.max(1, Math.ceil(x/80));}
  function  handle(mail)
  {
    $("emails").value = mail;
  }

</script>
     <table border=1 width=500px>

  {% for user, info in to_display.items %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type=checkbox value='{{user.email}}' onclick=handle("{{user.email}}")>
        {% for k , v in info.items %}
            {% if v != "" and k != "id" %}
              <b>{{k}} : </b>   {{v}} <br>
            {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </td></tr>
  {% endfor %}

        <form> <input id="emails">   </form>
```

Comment: Could you please share with us the whole code, markup and js code? Furthermore, as already thomas pointed out, you selector is not correct. Thanks

Comment: `type = "text/script" ` is not valid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change `<script type="text/script">` to `<script>` 
The browser assumes that a `<script>` includes javascript by default

Comment: mh why is my answer bad? it solves the error and its true (i think)

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` is standard. Did this really solve the issue?

Comment: in html5 the type attribute is optional, because as I said javascript is the standard script language. So <script> is the html5 standard.

Oh look I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323376/do-html5-script-tag-need-type-javascript

Comment: @NateBarbettini - Note the difference between `text/script` as posted by the OP and `text/javascript` which would have worked just as well as removing the explicit type.